# как сделать динамическую кнопку в писье на почте?

Tags: html

Отправляю пользователю на почту письмо с содержимым типа text/html.

Сам html следующего содержания:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/.config/usingYaml/templates/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" , name="newpass">
        <input type="text" name="newpasselse">
        <button formaction="http://ip.of.my.server:8282/new_password/" formmethod="post">Works</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Ожидаю, что, при  нажатии на кнопку Works, произойдет запрос на мой сервер, но ничего не происходит. Обработчик на сервере, естестенно, есть. Как сделать кнопку в письме, чтобы данные из форм отправились на сервер при нажатии кнопки?

UPD:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/.config/usingYaml/templates/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://my.ip.of.server:8282/new_password/" method="post">
        <input type="text" , name="newpass">
        <input type="text" name="newpasselse">
        <input type="submit" value="Works">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: formaction и formmethod пишутся в теге form

Comment: @UserTest013 ваше утверждение соответствует действительности лишь отчасти. Это действительно пишется в form, но не только там. Из уважения к попытке помочь, я сделал как вы говорите, эффект тот же(все еще не делает запрос). Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Из соображений безопасности почтовики вырезают формы.

Comment: @AlexeyTen А как же быть? Как осуществить отправку данных из письма?

Comment: Никак. Ставьте ссылку на сайт

Comment: https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-interactive-forms-in-email/ Ну т. е. они как-то где-то иногда работают, но в общем случае на них нельзя рассчитывать как на единственный способ